# How to terminate a running Thread in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, sockets

I am using socket in this code to connect with other machine.I want to terminate thread when i get message from other machine but how to terminate Thread in Python ?
I refer Many SO Questions and I found that there is no method in python to Close thread.Can anyone tell me the alternate way to close the thread ?

**code:**

```
from threading import Thread
import time
import socket

def background(arg):
    global thread
    thread = Thread(target=arg)
    thread.start()

def display():
    for i in range(0,20):
        print(i)
        time.sleep(5)

background(display)


s = socket.socket()
s.bind((ip,6500))
s.listen(5)
print("listening")

val,addr = s.accept()
cmd = val.recv(1024)
if cmd == "Terminate Process":
    print("Connected")
    thread.close()
    print("Process Closed")
```

**Error:**

```
AttributeError: 'Thread' object has no attribute 'close'
```

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Comment: python 2.7.....

Answer (score 5):

Short answer:

```
thread.join()
```

The rule of thumb is: don't kill threads (note that in some environments this may not even be possible, e.g. standard C++11 threads). Let the thread fetch the information and terminate itself. Controlling threads from other threads leads to hard to maintain and debug code.

E.g.

```
SHOULD_TERMINATE = False

def display():
    for i in range(0,20):
        print(i)
        time.sleep(5)
        if SHOULD_TERMINATE:
            return

thread = Thread(target=display)
thread.start()

// some other code
if cmd == "Terminate Process":
    SHOULD_TERMINATE = True
    thread.join()
```

This is of course heavily simplified. Your code can be further refined with [event objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#event-objects) (instead of `.sleep`) or thread pools.

Comment: thanks for solution but i am running some big process on actual code in cmd using thread and subprocess so this will not work there .

Comment: @sachindubey I don't see a relation between "big process" and "it won't work". Are you saying that you can't modify the underlying thread code?

Comment: @sachindubey Whether you like it or not, that's how it must be done.  Ultimately you must communicate to the thread (either via a global or an `Event`) that it needs to terminate and have it terminate itself.

Comment: i have a command which i need to run on cmd using subprocess so i am running that subprocess using threads and after that i am listening of client using socket ....If client tells me to stop then i need to stop that subprocess..

Comment: thanks @donkopotamus ya maybe Event can be a solution

Comment: @sachindubey I'm confused: are these processes or threads? Processes can be terminated by sending signals. Threads can't. You may find some hackish way to do that (depending on the underlying OS) but that's definitely not the way to go.